# Selected value as where argument

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `select` element:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   {!! Form::select('periodo', array(
    '1' => '2014-1', 
    '2' => '2014-2',
    '3' => '2015-1',
    '4' => '2015-2'), '4', ['class' => 'pull-right']) 
  !!}  
</div>
```

Those options of my `select` element are the first/second semesters of each year.
I need to use that value to bring data to the same page I'm at.
Something like :

`Select * from myTable WHERE field = 2014-1`

I want to bring data by the selected value AND create a table with that data.
I know how to do it passing data from my Controller and also already created the and populated the data. my Controller:

```
public function getProfessorList()
    {
        return View::make('professor', [
            'professor' => Professor::orderBy('name','asc')->get()
        ]);
    }
```

With the code above, I send all data to my view, but I need to filter it by the selected value of my `select` element. How may I do that ? Should I make a `POST` in my page sending it to the same page I'm at but this time with the selected value as a parameter? Is this the best way to go ?